# What's better use for storing settings with gtkmm-3?

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm, gconf

I writing simple program in C++ using gtkmm-3.

I need to store some settings in form of several numbers and strings.

I found gconfmm, but it's seems only for Gtk 2.

Will it work together? Or there is better way to store settings?

Comment: I personally would write a custom class for settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class [Gio::Settings](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1Settings.html) in gtkmm. It's wrap [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) and can be used for this task.